# How can I draw a frustum like this?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I am trying to draw a frustum with centers of two bases `A`, `C` and two radii `SA` and `CD`, height of frustum `AC`.

[image]

I tried

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{70}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,declare function={a=2;
        }]
        \path 
        (0,0,0) coordinate (A)
        (a,0,0) coordinate (B)
        (a,a,0) coordinate (C)
        (0,2*a,0) coordinate (D)
         (0,0,2*a)  coordinate (S)
        ;
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--(S) -- cycle (S) -- (B) (S) --(C);
\draw [dashed] (D) -- (A) -- (C);
\path foreach \p/\g in {A/-90,B/-90,C/0,D/0,S/90}{(\p)node{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I got

[image]

How can I draw it?

Comment: What are the *centers* of a frustum?

Comment: @Bernard Updated.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Could you post a hand-made sketch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [3dtools](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools)

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools,calc}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=55,psi=0,theta=70},
        line join = round, line cap = round,
        c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},
        declare function={a=2;r=a*sqrt(2);R=2*a;}]
        \path 
        (0,0,0) coordinate (A) 
        (a,0,0) coordinate (B)
        (a,a,0) coordinate (C) 
        (0,2*a,0) coordinate (D)
        (0,0,2*a) coordinate (S)
        [3d coordinate={(S')=(C)-(D) +(A)}];
            \tikzset{3d/define orthonormal dreibein={A={(A)},B={(S)},C={(S')}}} 
        \path[x={(ex)},y={(ey)},z={(ez)}](A) pic{3d/frustum={r=r,R=R,h=r}};
        \draw[3d/visible](C) -- (D);
    \draw[3d/hidden](S) --(A) -- (B) -- (C) (S) -- (C) (S) -- (D) (A) -- (C) (A) -- (D) (S) -- (B);             
        \path foreach \p/\g in {A/180,B/-90,C/-90,D/0,S/90}
        {(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools,calc}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
\foreach \Angle in {5,15,...,355}  
{\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=\Angle,psi=0,theta=70},
        line join = round, line cap = round,same bounding box=A,
        c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},
        declare function={a=2;r=a*sqrt(2);R=2*a;}]
        \path 
        (0,0,0) coordinate (A) 
        (a,0,0) coordinate (B)
        (a,a,0) coordinate (C) 
        (0,2*a,0) coordinate (D)
        (0,0,2*a) coordinate (S)
        [3d coordinate={(S')=(C)-(D) +(A)}];
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myB}{TD("(C)")}   
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{screendepth(\myB)>0?1:0}
        \ifnum\itest=1
        \draw[3d/visible] (C) -- (D);
        \draw[3d/hidden] (S) -- (A);
        \else
        \draw[3d/hidden] (D) -- (C);
        \draw[3d/visible] (S) -- (A);
        \fi   
        \draw[3d/hidden] (A) -- (C)  (A) -- (D) -- (S)
        (A) -- (B) -- (C) (S) -- (B)  -- (C) -- cycle
        ;
        \tikzset{3d/define orthonormal dreibein={A={(A)},B={(S)},C={(S')}}} 
        \path[x={(ex)},y={(ey)},z={(ez)}](A) pic{3d/frustum={r=r,R=R,h=r}};     
        \path foreach \p/\g in {A/180,B/-90,C/-90,D/0,S/90}
        {(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Update and finish.

```
import three;
import solids;

size(8cm);
currentprojection=orthographic((1,-.2,.3));

real a=2;
triple A=O,B=(a,0,0),C=(a,a,0),D=(0,2a,0),S=(0,0,2a);
triple D_=rotate(-90,C,A)*D;

draw(C--D);
draw(A--S--B--cycle,dashed);
draw(A--C^^A--D,dashed);

revolution R=revolution(A,D_--S,C);
draw(C--D_,Arrow3);
//draw(surface(R),green+opacity(.5));
draw(R,linewidth(0.6bp));

path3 c=circle(C,abs(C-D),A-C);
// draw(c,Arrow3); // To specify the direction of circle
path c_=project(c);

draw(subpath(c,reltime(c,0.3),reltime(c,0.5)),green+0.8bp,Arrow3);
dot(relpoint(c,0.3));
dot(relpoint(c,0.5));

path pvisib1 = cut(project(D--S--C),c_,1).before;
path pvisib2 = cut(project(D--S--C),c_,2).after;
path pcache = cut(cut(project(D--S--C),c_,1).after,c_,1).before;
path BCdashed = cut(project(C--B),c_,1).after;
path BC = cut(project(C--B),c_,1).before;

// three.asy, line 1163
draw(invert(pvisib1),blue);
draw(invert(pvisib2),blue);
draw(invert(BC),blue);
draw(invert(pcache)^^invert(BCdashed),red+dashed);

dot("$A$",A,dir(-135));
dot("$B$",B,dir(-90));
dot("$C$",C,dir(-35));
dot("$D$",D,dir(0));
dot("$S$",S,dir(90));
```

[image]

Additional code for **revolution**

```
import graph;
import solids;
currentprojection=orthographic(3,3,1.5);
//currentlight=Viewport;
currentlight.background = gray(.7);

picture pic1,pic2;
size(pic1,200);
size(pic2,200);
path g= (0, 0.65){right}
..{up}(0.45, 1)
--(0.5, 1){down}
..{left}(0.1,0.6)
{right}..{down}(0.15,0.55)
..{down}(0.075,0.35){down}
..{down}(0.075, 0.2)
..(0.15,0.15){down}
..{left}(0.1,0.1){right}
..{right}(0.4,0.05)
--(0.4,0){left}
..{left}(0,0.05);
pen[] colors={red,green,blue};
colors.cyclic=true;

for(int i=0;i<length(g);++i){

draw(pic1,subpath(g,i,i+1),colors[i]+1bp);
path3 p=path3(subpath(g,i,i+1),YZplane);
revolution R=revolution(p,Z,0,300);
draw(pic2,surface(R),colors[i],meshpen=black+0.55bp);

}
xaxis(pic1,"$x$",Arrow());
yaxis(pic1,"$y$",Arrow());

picture pic;
picture pic3;
add(pic,pic1.fit(),(0,0),15W);
add(pic,pic2.fit(),(0,0),15E);
draw(pic3,(-15,0)--(15,0),Arrow);
add(pic,pic3.fit());
add(pic.fit(),Fill(gray(.7)));
```

[image]

Animation.

```
import graph;
import solids;

currentprojection=orthographic(3,3,1.5);
//currentlight.background = gray(.7);

size(8cm);

path g= (0, 0.65){right}
..{up}(0.45, 1)
--(0.5, 1){down}
..{left}(0.1,0.6)
{right}..{down}(0.15,0.55)
..{down}(0.075,0.35){down}
..{down}(0.075, 0.2)
..(0.15,0.15){down}
..{left}(0.1,0.1){right}
..{right}(0.4,0.05)
--(0.4,0){left}
..{left}(0,0.05);

pen[] colors={red,green,blue};
colors.cyclic=true;

int numberofframes=72;
string[] files;

// Optional arguments and "normal" is always coincide with orthographic(3,3,1.5)
path3 boundingbox = circle((3,3,2), r=0.7, normal=(3,3,1.5)); 

for (int j=37; j<=numberofframes; ++j)
{
  files[j]="T"+(string) j;
  picture pic;
  draw(pic, boundingbox, invisible);
  for(int i=0;i<length(g);++i)
  {
    path3 p=path3(subpath(g,i,i+1),YZplane);
    revolution R=revolution(p,Z,0,j*5);
    draw(pic,surface(R),colors[i],meshpen=black+0.51bp);
  }
  add(pic);
  shipout(files[j],bbox(invisible));
  erase();
}
```

[image]

Compile with [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/).

Compile at http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/

From [solids.asy](https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/blob/master/base/solids.asy)

```
// A surface of revolution generated by rotating a planar path3 g
// from angle1 to angle2 about c--c+axis.
revolution revolution(triple c=O, path3 g, triple axis=Z, real angle1=0, real angle2=360);
```

Code

```
import three;
import solids;

size(8cm);
currentprojection=orthographic((1,-.2,.3));

real a=2;
triple A=O,B=(a,0,0),C=(a,a,0),D=(0,2a,0),S=(0,0,2a);
triple D_=rotate(-90,C,A)*D;

draw(A--B--C--D);
draw(A--S--B^^C--S--D);
draw(A--C^^A--D,dashed);

revolution R=revolution(A,D_--S,C);
draw(C--D_,Arrow3);
//draw(surface(R),green+opacity(.5));
draw(R,linewidth(0.6bp));

dot("$A$",A,dir(-135));
dot("$B$",B,dir(-90));
dot("$C$",C,dir(-35));
dot("$D$",D,dir(0));
dot("$S$",S,dir(90));
```

with `D_--S` is a generatrix and `A--C` is the directrix.

[image]

Comment: How can I put this code between `\begin{document} ... \end{document}` ?

Comment: I try your code at http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ and try rotate by hand, dashed line of the circle incorrect.

Comment: @ThuyNguyen Be patient! You will get a `tikz-3dplot` or`3dtools` from experienced users.

Comment: @NguyenVanChi1998: Do you know anything about the status of `3dtools` or the author? What made you suggest it?

Comment: @hpekristiansen :-)), marmot is not on this, and he(she) also left https://topanswers.xyz/tex. I don't know `tikz-3dplot` or `3dtools` and relative things but I see many good answers with them, so I think experienced users will not ignore this question.

Comment: @NguyenVanChi1998 Am I wrong? I think, blue segments on three segments `SC` , `BC` and `SD` must be hidden segments like answer of minhthien_2016?

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter You imagine it as a frustum without the lid. :-))

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter I see several line segments are not true, however, I will not edit my answer anymore. Lol. It can be considered as an exercise for anyone who really care about `Asymptote`.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{70}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,declare function={a=2;}]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (a,0,0);
\coordinate (C) at (a,a,0); 
\coordinate (D) at (0,2*a,0); 
\coordinate (S) at (0,0,2*a); 
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--(S) -- cycle (S) -- (B) (S) --(C);
\draw [dashed] (A) -- (D)  (A) -- (C);
\path foreach \p/\g in {A/-90,B/-90,C/0,D/0,S/90}{(\p)node{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}}; 
\begin{scope}[plane origin={(0,0,0)}, plane x={(1,-1,0)}, plane y={(0,0,1)}, canvas is plane]
 \draw (0,0) circle (2*a);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[plane origin={(a,a,0)}, plane x={(a+1,a-1,0)}, plane y={(a,a,1)}, canvas is plane]
 \draw (0,0) circle (a);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Diagram with two slanted circles]

`\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{50}` :

[image: Same diagram with different orientation]

`\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{100}` :

[image: Yet another orientation]