# can I draw 2D and 3D graph in one output file with asymptote

Tags: diagrams, asymptote, draw

I would like to have two pictures in one output file like on the picture. The code down here makes an output as two overlapping, I would like to have the one beside the second.

[image: graph x^3 and x^2+y^2]

```
 size(11cm,0);
    import graph;
    import graph3;
    import geometry;
    
//colors
pen dBlue1=rgb(66/255, 81/255, 172/255);
pen dRed=rgb(237/255, 27/255, 43/255);
pen dGray=rgb(130/255, 130/255, 130/255);    

defaultpen(0.7bp+dGray+ fontsize(14pt));    
pen pblue=1.1bp+dBlue1; // 
pen pred=1.1bp+dRed;    // 

real as=3bp;    

picture pic1,pic2;

limits(pic1,(-2,2),(-4,4));
xaxis(pic1,Label("$x$"),Arrow(as));
yaxis(pic1,Label("$y$"),Arrow(as));

real f(real x) {return ((x)^3); };
draw(pic1,Label("$y=x^3$",position=Relative(0.9)),graph(f,-1.6,1.6),pred);
add(pic1);

real F(pair z) {
  return z.x^2+z.y^2;
}

currentprojection=orthographic(3,2,1);

limits(pic2,(-2,-2,-1),(2,2,3));
xaxis3(pic2,"$x$",Arrow3);
yaxis3(pic2,"$y$",Arrow3);
zaxis3(pic2,"$z$",Arrow3);

draw(pic2,surface(F,(-1,-1),(1,1),nx=16,Spline),
                   lightblue+opacity(0.5),pblue);

add(shift(5.5,0)*pic2);

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/615968/236162

Comment: @NguyenVanChi1998 thank you.